# python3 is not recognized as an internal or external command.operable program or batch file

Tags: windows-7, python, cmd.exe, python3

i have **python 3.8.6** installed in my **Windows 7 x64** .Whenever i try to run **python3** as a command.it gives me an message stating that **python3 is not recognized as an internal or external command.operable program or batch file** but when i run **python** as a command , it works absolutely fine. i tried adding my python folder in system variables>path but nothing changes

Comment: Does the `python3` executable exist? What's wrong with using `python` rather than `python3`?

Comment: Have you added the path to your Python installation directory to your PATH environment system variable?

Comment: Remove Python and install following this ***[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60479607/8177207)***

Comment: @gronostaj yes python3.8.6 executable exists and i want to python3 because i want to run sherlock

Comment: @Ramhound yes I have added 
read my question again, I have written that.

Comment: Read up how PATH works. Command line will look up commands in PATH folders, but if there's no executable called `python3` in any PATH folder, the command won't be recognized.

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe I tried it  but still not working

Comment: @Sodead If you type **`py`** and after **`where /r \ Python3.*`** what these commands return to you?

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39910730/python3-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program).

There is no python3.exe file, that is why it fails.
So, try run:

```
py
```

And "py" is just a launcher for python.exe. If you have more than one python versions installed on your machine (2.x, 3.x) you can specify what version of python to launch by:

```
py -2 or py -3
```